# Arquillian vs Mockito vs Embeddable API vs another framework to run jUnit

Tags: junit, ejb, mockito, jboss-arquillian

I'm looking for a framework to run jUnit tests written for EJB.

What's the best framework? Why?

I've found Arquillian, Mockito and Embeddable API.
What the alternative framework besides them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good unit test has a few important characteristics one of which is to Mock external dependencies and for that you'll need a mocking framework. Mockito is a good mocking framework. Jmockit is another one. Arquillian, however, is an integration testing framework and not a unit testing one.